# Finding lowest odd number in a Linked List in python

Tags: python, linked-list

I am newly learning about Linked Lists and my assigment requires me to make a function that returns the lowest odd number...and I think I have done that in my `get_min_odd` function.
I believe my code is only checking the first and second element of the linked list so my question is how can I iterate through a linked list to find the lowest odd number? I would think a for loop but I don't understand what list I'm iterating through...which brings up another question, where are the elements in a linked list stored if not in a list, array, string, etc.?

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    #def.....

    def add_all(self, a_list):
        newNode = Node(a_list)
        newNode.next = self.head
        self.head = newNode
        for i in a_list:
            self.next = i 

    def add_all(self, a_list):
        for i in range(len(a_list)):
            self.add(a_list[i])
    
    def get_min_odd(self):
        lst = []
        if self.head.data % 2 == 1:
            lst.append(self.head.data)
        elif self.head.next.data % 2 == 1:
            lst.append(self.head.next.data)
        else:
            return 999
        return min(lst)

my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.add_all([1, 4, -3, 6, 9, 2, 10001, 25, 19, 20])
print(my_list.get_min_odd())
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- You have two methods that are called `add_all`. This means the first one will be lost. You actually need an `add` method instead of that first `add_all`. And it should not take a *list* as value, but just a single numeric value. That method should not have to loop (Moreover, assigning `i` to the same `next` attribute over and over again makes no sense).
- `get_min_odd` is indeed too much fixed on the first and second node. They might not even exist when the list is short or empty. To *loop* over a linked list, you need a name that first equals the head node, but then *traverses* along the `next` attributes to the next node, and then the next, ... until it reaches the end.
- `get_min_odd` should not create a list with values. That defeats the purpose of a linked linked list. Instead that code should immediately update the minimum it has *while* traversing the linked list.

Here is the updated code for the two methods that needed correction:

```
   def add(self, value):  # name and arg name correction
        newNode = Node(value)
        newNode.next = self.head
        self.head = newNode
```

and:

```
    def get_min_odd(self):
        result = None
        node = self.head
        while node: # as long as the end of the list is not encountered...
            if node.data % 2 == 1:
                # adjust the result to the minimum data encountered so far
                result = node.data if result is None else min(result, node.data)
            node = node.next  # traverse to next node
        return result
```